# Print a triangle of number

Tags: java

How can I print this?

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
public static void printNumber(int x) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(i + " " +(i + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: You need two nested for

Comment: Can we do it one for?

Comment: you can use string concat if u want to do in one for loop

Comment: There might be a way but it is more complicated than using 2 fors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 for loop  is a good solution .but if you want by just one loop.you can use string concatenate like this .but string concatenate inside a big loop is not good.string builder can be used instead string

```
String s="";
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    s += " " + (i + 1);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

output

```
 1
 1 2
 1 2 3
 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call your print statement once for each line of output you want. For each line, create or clear a StringBuilder and populate it with the numbers, with a space after each number, then call `System.out.println(sb.toString())`;

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {

            sb.append(j);
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
```

gives the following:

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two loops to print it.

1) First to control the number of rows.
2) To print the numbers.

```
for(int x=1;x<=4;x++){
   for(int y=1;y<=x;y++){
     System.out.print(y+" ");
   }
   System.out.println("");
}
```